# AWS Cognito finding right Parameters for CognitoSyncDemo

Tags: authentication, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I'm going to setup [this Example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) for Amazon Cognito Sync demo, using Eclipse + ADK + AWS libs V2.9.

1. I created an identity pool in the Cognito Console, so I got the Identity Pool ID which is used in CognitoSyncClientManager.java at:

   ```
   private static final String IDENTITY_POOL_ID = "us-east-1:1a23b013-1abc-123-b123-123abc1fe5";
   private static final Regions REGION = Regions.US_EAST_1;**
   ```

(perhaps not all regions seem to run in test mode)

2. I registered my (developing-)app in the Seller Central with Eclipse Help>Android>Bild>MD5 fingerprint and the package-name from AndroidManifest.xml, so  got my api_key.txt Value.
3. From the [AWS doku](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_sync_region) I got my Provider URL (code as sample), which is used in DeveloperAuthenticationProvider.java at:

   ```
   private static final String developerProvider = "cognito-sync.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
   private static final String cognitoSampleDeveloperAuthenticationAppEndpoint = "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/Cognito_TestMyAppAuth_DefaultRole"
   private static final String cognitoSampleDeveloperAuthenticationAppName = "Cognito sync demo";
   ```

After creating some Users which are attached to groups with permissions to IAM full access and (auto)generated roles for unautherized and autherized Roles, my app is running in this way:

- Login with Amazon - is running, but where will their datasets be created and is it possible I see them in the AWS Console?
- Simple Browse your data (without login) - is running, unauthenticated users and their datasets appear/are counted in the Identity console
- Developer Authentication fails with Username or password do not match - combined with an "Unable to reach resource..." in the LogCat.

Now I think, the last missing thing in this game is the parameter cognitoSampleDeveloperAuthenticationAppEndpoint=... 
Where can I find it and what else could I have missed to setup for a full running Example?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using Cognito demo. Answers to your questions

1. Yes, you can see the datasets in the AWS console. Navigate to Cognito inside the AWS Console and go to your identity pool. On the left hand side menu go to identity browser and you will see the list of identities or you can search for an identity. Click on the identity and you can see the datasets owned by that identity.
2. Developer Authentication is a feature which helps to integrate your authentication system with Cognito. For this you should have a backend server serving user's authentication requests, and once you authenticate users you can request OpenId Connect tokens for them from Cognito using the GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity API call. The developer provider name is the one which you setup for your identity pool in the AWS Cognito console. For using the sample you can setup a sample server application by following this [blog](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) and the [readme](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample) file of the the server side application.

P.S.: Please avoid sharing your identity pool id.

Thanks,
Rachit

Comment: I am curious, is it bad practice to share your identity pool id? When using the cognito identity js library (https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) it would be pretty easy to find it out from the client.

Comment: Yes, identity pool id can be found in the way you mentioned, that is why it is highly recommended to use authenticated identities for resource sensitive operations.
But sharing it in SO makes it much easier for someone to get it without even your app/web-app :)

Comment: That is true it's not a great idea to post those ids on public forums or Q&A sites, however you cannot avoid this when deploying your website publicly, right? I guess you could use obfuscation to make it harder to find?